# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType' while trying to implement dynamic programming

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
n=2
c=0
def position(x,y):
    print "x and y is",x,y
    global n,c
    if(x==n or y==n):  
         c=c+1
         return c
    else:
        position(x,y+1)+position(x+1,y)
    print c     

position(0,0)
```

I dont understand why I am getting incompatible type error .I tried tracing the code but to me it should work right.Where am I going wrong in this?

Answer (score 0):

In the `else` clause:

```
position(x,y+1)+position(x+1,y)
```

the expression is calculated but no explicit `return` is used, thus `None` is returned. Change this line to:

```
return position(x,y+1)+position(x+1,y)
```

Comment: None is returned to what.I mean every time the function call ends with the if clause so it should return an integer.

Comment: `None` is returned to the caller and in this case the `position()` function called from the `else` clause. And when that call also ends in the `else` clause then there is `None` returned which can't be added to a number.